# Why can you define a lambda with a name in the capture-list of a lambda-expression, but not outside of it?

Tags: c++, lambda, syntax

I've read the explanation of lambda expressions in C++, and I've seen how they work, and how a [lambda-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.general#:lambda-expression) needs to be declared (many details omitted):

> `[` *[lambda-capture](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#nt:lambda-capture)*<sub>opt</sub> `]` `(` *[parameter-declaration-clause](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#nt:parameter-declaration-clause)* `)` *[compound-statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#nt:compound-statement)*.

I've seen that you can define a lambda inside another lambda definition in a way like this:

```cpp
[lambda1{[](){
    return 123;
}}]{
    return lambda1();
}
```

This works:

```
cout << [lambda1{[](){
    return 123;
}}]{
    return lambda1();
}();
```

This one doesn't:

```
cout << prova{[](){
    return "hello";
}}();
```

Why can I define it like `lambda1{...}` in the second example and not in the third?

Comment: `lambda1` in the first example is an init-capture, effectively equivalent to declaring a variable `auto lambda1{[](){ return 123; }};` and then capturing it in the outer lambda.

Comment: A lambda capture, the thing inside `[  ]`, has [special syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).  Your example `lambda1{...}` uses version (3) `identifier initializer`. You can use that as a declaration elsewhere by prefixing an `auto` (not needed in the lambda capture).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example, `[lambda1{[](){...}}]{...}` you see that the identifier `lambda1` occurs within brackets`[]` that are the capture list of the lambda. This is a context where a *new* identifier, `lambda1`, can be declared.

In the third example, the identifier `prova` occurs without any "special" context, in particular, not one where a new identifier can be declared. Hence, it is looked up in the usual way, and if it is not found, you have an error.

Comment: also why can i declare lambda1 like this: lamda1{...}. I haven't found the explanation for this type of declaration anywhere

Comment: `[lambda1{[](){}}] {...}` is just another way of writing `[lambda1 = [](){}] {...}`, just as the `[x = 0] {...}`.